# Spring MVC - Erro 405

Tags: spring-mvc

Estou tentando subir uma aplicação configurada com Spring e está apresentando erro *405*.

**Controller:**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/solicitacaoDeMaterial")
public class SolicitacaoMaterialController {

    @Autowired
    private SolicitacaoService solicitacaoService;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<?> get() {
            return new ResponseEntity<>("Solicitacão incluída com sucesso", HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<?> salvar(@RequestBody SolicitacaoVO solicitacao) {
        try {
            solicitacaoService.salvar(solicitacao);
            return new ResponseEntity<>("Solicitacão incluída com sucesso", HttpStatus.OK);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return new ResponseEntity<String>("Ocorreu um erro " + e.getMessage(), HttpStatus.OK);
        }
    }

Mapeamento da página:

$scope.salvarDados = function () {
            $scope.solicitacao.produtos = $scope.produtos;
            $http({
                method : "POST",
                url : "solicitacaoDeMaterial",
                data: $scope.solicitacao
            }).then(function myChessus(response) {
                console.log(response)
            }, function myError(response) {
                console.log(response)
            });
        };
```

*Obs*: Já acrescentei a `base href="/formularios/"` no head da página.